# Why is my React Input box not rendering delayed response even though the wrapper class renders the input box - React with Redux

Tags: reactjs

**Problem statement:** The class render() is called but the underlying input box does not update field.

**Description:** When the app Class is loaded, I make a fetch config call to get the initial server config. Before the async calls, the input box successfully shows the initial value. However, after the async data is loaded, the class calls the render method but input value would not change.

**Code:
InputBoxComponent**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const StatefulInputBox = (props) => {

    const [inputValue, changeInputValue] = useState(props.value);

    console.log(inputValue);
    const onChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;

        changeInputValue(val);

        if(props.onChange) {
            props.onChange(val);
        }
    }

    return (
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => {
            onChange(e)
        }} />
    )
};
```

**WrapperClass**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {nameActions} from "../../actions/inputBoxActions";
import {StatefulInputBox} from "./StatefulInputBox";

class StatefulNumInputBoxWrapperStoreComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super();

        console.log(props.inputConfig);
        props.getThunkNum();

        this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
    }

    //props.getInputBoxNum();
    // Without a button this goes in an infinite self rendering loop
    // That is why we use a class wrapper, so that the constructor isn't called multiple times

    onValueChange (newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <StatefulInputBox value={this.props.inputConfig.value} onChange={this.onValueChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapInputWrapperStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        inputConfig: state.inputBox
    }
}

const mapInputWrapperDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getInputBoxNum: () => (dispatch(nameActions.getInputBoxNum())),
        setInputBoxNum: (name) => (dispatch(nameActions.setInputBoxNum(name))),
        getThunkNum: () => (dispatch(nameActions.getThunkNum()))
    }
}

export const StatefulNumInputWrapperStoreClass = connect(mapInputWrapperStateToProps, mapInputWrapperDispatchToProps)(StatefulNumInputBoxWrapperStoreComponent);
```

**InputBoxAction**

```
export const nameActions = {
    getInputBoxNum: () => {
        return {
            type: 'GET_INPUTBOX_NUM',
            payload: {
                loading: false,
                value: 10
            }
        }
    },
    setInputBoxNum: (num) => {
        return {
            type: 'SET_INPUTBOX_NUM',
            payload: {
                loading: false,
                value: num
            }
        }
    },
    getThunkNum: () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(nameActions.setLoading());
            setTimeout(()=>{
                dispatch(nameActions.setInputBoxNum(50));
            },2000)

        }
    }
};
```

**InputBoxReducer**

```
const initialState = {
    value: 'Joe',
    loading: false
}

export const nameReducer = (currentState = {...initialState}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_INPUTBOX_NUM': {
            const newState = {...currentState, ...action.payload};
            return newState;
        }
        case 'SET_INPUTBOX_NUM': {
            const newState = {...currentState, ...action.payload};
            return newState;
        }
        case 'NAME_SUCCESS': {
            let newState = {...currentState, ...action.payload};

            return newState;
        }
        default: {
            return currentState;
        }
    }
}
```

**Store**

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {buttonReducer} from "./components/Button/buttonReducers";
import {nameReducer} from "./reducers/inputBoxReducer";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {dropDownReducer} from "./reducers/dropDownReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    button: buttonReducer,
    inputBox: nameReducer,
    dropDown: dropDownReducer
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

**Few things to note:**
All the data flow points are indicating change, meaning the constructor, the actions, the reducer, the mapStateToProps, then the class render. What is not working is the inputBox value. The console log inside the InputBox is not called after the async call.
I have used controlled form as there would be prefilled data.
I tried the wrapper with a pure component but it goes on an infinite loop as getThunkNum keeps getting called repetitively

*Also suggest, what would be a better strategy to work with a default prefilled data, initial config load data, and then the normal flow of editing.*

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the fetch API inside componentDidMount() of the wrapper class but still no luck.

**UPDATE 2**
I am receiving value from props but my input value is pointing to inputValue, a property of state object. So how do I decide if I should print the props or state property?

Comment: It would be great if you can create a sandbox

Comment: @Jagrati can you help me how to create one please?

Comment: I added a force update 
if(props.value !== inputValue) {
    changeInputValue(props.value);
}
But that blocks changes typed :'(

Comment: I've made a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-my-react-input-box-not-re-rendering-even-though-the-wrapper-class-renders-yvjrf?file=/src/actions/inputBoxActions.js

This seems to work for me. Edit it to make it break please. A tip: you have to call super(props) in the constructor.

Comment: @xabitrigo Hi, you are correct initially. It should be Joe. But after 2 seconds, the value should be 50 as returned by action - getThunkNum. But I got the problem. Posting it in a new answer

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured out the problem.

When you have the issue of showing a default value, a pre-loaded server data (pre-fill) AND making them editable. It's best not to mix props and useState. A direct redux approach of changing the store value on every change solves the problem.

In the above problem, the inputBox looked like this:
import React, {useState} from 'react';

```
export const StatefulInputBox = (props) => {

    const [inputValue, changeInputValue] = useState(props.value);

    console.log(inputValue);
    const onChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;

        changeInputValue(val);

        if(props.onChange) {
            props.onChange(val);
        }
    }

    return (
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => {
            onChange(e)
        }} />
    )
};
```

Notice, the ambiguity while assigning value to the input box. If you assign props.value, then the user can't type. And if you assign value=inputValue then it can't be changed by the server call data.

I removed the useState feature and directed changes through redux itself

```
export const DelayedResInputBox = (props) => {

    return (
        <input value={props.value} onChange={(e) => {
            props.onChange(e.target.value)
        }} />
    )
};
```

And in the wrapper class, I wired the updates to store using redux

```
class DelayedResWrapperComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(val) {
        console.log(val);

        this.props.saveUserResponse(val)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getServerData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DelayedResInputBox value={this.props.delayedRes.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        )
    }
}

const mapDelayedDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getServerData: () => {
            dispatch(delayedResActions.getDelayedThunkRes())
        },
        saveUserResponse: (val) => {
            dispatch(delayedResActions.setValueInStore(val))
        }
    }
};
```

This way all the minor changes are routed through store and the inputBox gets only one change command. Hence, I achieved the goal by updating store via redux.

Note: Change in store does not mean submit. All smaller components will update store with their value and then a submit button will only trigger a server update. This also helps to pull out unnecessary logic in a dumb component

The only other approach would be to have three input boxes: a disabled one to show data till the config loading completes, an editable one with useState

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. React is based on Components, which rerender ONLY if their props or internal state changes. This state is LOCAL. But Components are easier if they are stateless. Redux just treats the whole application as a big Component, with a GLOBAL state that is transferred to the components via props (mapStateToProps). It also provides you with a formal method to change the global state: dispatching actions (which are mapped to props so you can use them, mapDispatchToProps) that are processed in a central place (the reducer).

Comment: To be clear: Redux interacts with React using props, never using state. No ambiguity here.

Comment: @xabitrigo you are only talking about the `connect` function from `react-redux`, props are not relevant to hooks used by `react-redux` or with `redux` itself. Even for `connect` it's only half of the story, because the component returned by `connect` uses React `context` to read from the global store.

Comment: @Tarun I am happy if you solved your problem, but this is not an answer to your question and your explanation is wrong and won't help any future readers. Please feel free to write an actual [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) with actual code that solved your problem. e.g. "When I stopped mixing props with useState to simplify my components, it fixed my problem. I am now using following code: "

Comment: @Tarun the implementation details don't matter for this problem. You read and manipulate the global Redux state through the props and only through the props, which you need to map explicitly. You said there is ambiguity, and there is not. You use the explicit variable that you want, no ambiguity there.

Comment: @Tarun IMHO You are having problems understanding how React works. In order to change the value of the input of a controlled component you NEED a new render, and this only happens if some prop or some internal state changes.

So you need to either make `props.value` change (which you can do with redux... or with the internal state of the parent component if you want). Or use the `inputValue` which you store in the local state.

Take a slow look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.